# Creating GSON object error

Tags: java, servlets, gson

I'm trying to create Gson object inside Java Servlet class.

```
public class SendNews extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            System.out.println("Before creating");
            Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
            System.out.println("This line and the whole code below will be skipped.");
            System.out.println("And this method will be finished without Exceptions.");

        }
    }
```

I've tried to use

```
Gson gsonB = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

The same problem. After I create the `Gson` object, the method returns without any of the prints statements being executed or any exception being logged.

But the code below works fine:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //GcmSender.post(new NewsContent());
        System.out.println("Before creating");
        Gson gsonB = new Gson();
        System.out.println("After creating");

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using google gson library v2.3.1

Comment: After I declared gson object I can't use it, because it finishes doPost() method and I don't know why.

Comment: question is bit vague .. .is your program compiling...do you have proper import statements... did you try to debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is a mainstream library.

It seems that your issue is related to your server setup: your compile your servlet with Gson library in classpath (and it also is in classpath when you run your program, perhaps from IDE).

But when you put your **war** to the server (where Gson is missed) `doPost` teminates when encounters `new Gson()`. So make sure that you have Gson library **jar** in classpath both when compile time and run time.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I put the gson jar to the WEB-INF folder... instead of the WEB-INF\lib path